# MongoDB + node.js - SQL Select equivalent

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm pretty new to node.js and mongodb. I need a function, that will return an array with results from database. When I query 'SELECT * FROM table' in php, it returns array or array of objects. But with node and mongo I have to use lot of code, which seems so unnecessary to me. So I wrote this function:

```
select: function (table, terms) {
    var rows = [];
    var find = function (error, db) {
        var collection = db.collection(table);
        var docs = collection.find(terms);
        docs.each(function (error, doc) {
            rows.push(doc);
        });
    };
    client.connect(url, find);
    return rows;
}
```

It takes table name [string] and terms [js object] as arguments. And I want to this function return an array like this: [ { doc1 }, { doc2 }, { doc3 }, ...].
When I log variable doc, in each function, it's alright - valid javascript object. But when I log variable rows after pushing all docs, it's empty - []. Also the result of function select() is empty array - [].

Please, is there someone who has an idea about what could be a problem or who uses some similar method to fetch data from MongoDB? Thank you

Comment: you can still use ORM like mongoose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connect function is asynchronous, and finishes after your return statement. Put your return statement within the callback function, just after the closing bracket of docs.each(.....); This way you're sure your return statement will be executed after your array has been filled.

Edit for completeness: a return statement doesn't work of course, because it returns from the function in find. Work with a callback function.

Like this:

```
select: function (table, terms, cb) {
    var rows = [];
    var find = function (error, db) {
        var collection = db.collection(table);
        var docs = collection.find(terms);
        docs.each(function (error, doc) {
            rows.push(doc);
        });
        cb(error, rows);
    };
    client.connect(url, find);
}
```

Edit: Above example (cb function instead of return)

Comment: Well, I tried that, but the problem is, the return statement is now in callback function, so it returns rows within callback not within select function. Now, when I call select it returns nothing (function without return value) - undefind. I think this is big limit within whole javascript, how to return value from callback. But thanks

Comment: Yes true, was overlooking that. But to overcome that, you could pass a third parameter to the select function, which is another callback function. function (table, terms, cb). When finished, you call return cb(rows), or better cb(error, rows).

Comment: Yeah, this is good idea, unfortunately I'm using project structure which makes this pretty complicated. There is a model for accessing database (code above is from there), when http route is called, I call a function from particular model, from here select function is called and then it process results and returns formated data back to route. So it would take a very lot of callbacks. But seems I'll have to do it this way full of callbacks. Maybe I implement mongoose or something like this in future.

Comment: Many times in JavaScript callbacks are the only way to go because of the asynchronous character of many calls. This is something you have to keep in mind during the design. Many callbacks can cause ugly and unclear code (nested callbacks...), look up the async module (good link here http://justinklemm.com/node-js-async-tutorial/) to keep your code clear.